# Cake PHP: 3.0- Use of Collections

Tags: php, cakephp, collections

Am new to Cake PHP and MVC, I [read this](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/collections.html#Cake%5CCollection%5CCollection::shuffle)  tutorial for Collections given in Cake book. When I call this code from the Controller(Sample Code) it returns like

> Cake\Collection\Collection Object ( )

Which should actually return like this [2, 3, 1]

Please correct me, If I had return the code wrongly or any namespace has been left out

**Sample Code**

```
   <?php 
   namespace App\Controller;
   use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
   use Cake\Collection\Collection;
   class AdminController extends AppController 
   {
     public function collection()
      {
      $items = ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3];
      $collection = new Collection($items);


      // This could return [2, 3, 1]
      $collection->shuffle()->toArray();
      print_r($collection); exit;
     }
    } 
   ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to retrieve and output the array returned by `toArray`, not the `Collection`:

```
$arr = $collection->shuffle()->toArray () ;
print_r ($arr) ;
```

If you want to see the collection itself, use `debug`:

```
debug ($collection->shuffle ()) ;
```

Comment: I think you ment to print `$arr`. And note that `shuffle()` also doesn't modify the collection, it returns a new, shuffled one.